# Second report in Project always fails

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Ok, So I am learning SSRS, and I have come across the wierdest problem.

I created a new report project in 2008 studio.  Now I added a report just fine.  It runs, and everything is great!  So now I am trying to add a report that uses a parameter. I figured it would be simple, just add a parameter to the query, and "poof" microsoft would handle, but the report always fails.

So, I decided to take the query from my good report, Fail!  So I remove the query all together, Fail!  I delete the report and start over with no query, Fail!  I simply add a text box to the most basic of reports, and Fail!

I keep getting the same error:

```
Could not find file 'C:\MyReports\MYReports\bin\Debug\ReportFile.rdl'
```

Does anybody have an idea of why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: What does it mean that you "added" a report?. And, for the record, creating a report that uses a parameter is as simple as add a parameter to the query

Comment: That My first report was added to the project, and runs fine.  Its when trying to add a second report that everything falls apart.

Comment: Hoy are you "adding" reports?, "Add -> New Item"?

Comment: yep.  brand spanking new reports.  Tried thru both the wizard or a blank report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the solution and go to the properties.  In the 'Debug' section use the name of the report that you want to run.  It sounds like project looking to run a report that does not exists.

Comment: Checked that before, that wasn't the issue.

Comment: Most of the issues that I have seen have something wrong with the solution properties or the data source.

Comment: I agree that it must be something with the solution because I was able to create a new project and do all I was trying to without issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to clean the solution and rebuild the report. It looks like Visual Studio/Report builder is not putting the rdl file in that folder.

Comment: That didn't do it. I don't know if i missed this before, or if the clean did it, but It is saying that the report definition has not been specified

Comment: I think the problem was with the solution/Project and not the reports.  I decided to try creating a brand new solution and started added reports, and I have been unable to recreate the problem.  Is there something in the project level that i should be looking at?